# Why is the output current of the solar cell still continuous when using a buck converter for maximum power tracking of a solar array?

Tags: power-electronics, mppt

This is an PSIM example using buck converter to do MPPT:
[image]

My question is that since the solar cell array serves as the input source of the buck converter, according to the discontinuous characteristics of the input current of the buck converter, shouldn't the output current of the solar cell array be intermittent? Why do the simulation results show that the output current of the solar cell array is continuous?

Icell is the output current of solar cell array:

[image]

This is a normal buck converter. Regardless of whether the 1000u capacitor is added or not, the input current is still intermittent.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What bobflux said. || The panel output MUST be continuous to operate at maximum output. It has no energy storage mode. If it is not producing current is is not producing power and any power that it COULD have been producing is wasted - gone forever. || As TL notes, the filter capacitor serves to store panel energy. The buck converter should hold the capacitor at a voltage where the panel v x I are the maximum possible given current insolation conditions. || The converter can do what ever best suits the algorithm used AS LONG AS this results in Vpanel being optimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The panel output **MUST** be continuous to operate at maximum output.
It has no energy storage mode.
So, without energy storage, if it is not producing current is is not producing power and any power that it COULD have been producing is wasted - gone forever.

As bobflux notes, the filter capacitor serves to store panel energy - especially so at any time that the converter is not drawing current.
The buck converter should hold the capacitor at a mean voltage where the panel V x I are the maximum possible given current insolation conditions.

The converter can do whatever best suits the algorithm used AS LONG AS this results in Vpanel being optimum. The capacitor must be sized such that the variation in Vcap (= Vpanel) are small between periods of maximum inverter load and while the converter is not drawing current. In this context "small" means "acceptably small". Ideally the converter will hold the panel AT the optimum voltage, but an increase when not loaded of 1% or 5% or maybe 10% in voltage may have an acceptably small effect on overall efficiency.

For TRUE MPPT both the efficiency of the converter and the inverter's efficiency:load profile also matter.
Using Zxxx to mean "the efficiency of xxx" -
Zpanel x Zconverter = Zenergy transfer.
It may be that the converter is slightly more efficient at a voltage somewhere above Zpanel_max. So operating Vpanel slightly above that for Zpanel_max may result in a more efficient overall result.
A controller may achieve such an overall optimum result "unaware" of the factors at play, by applying feedback based on end to end efficiency, without taking account of how it is achieved in the various components.

Answer (score 5):

The input capacitor (1000uF in your schematic) does the trick.

When the buck FET is off, the solar cell charges the input cap. When the FET is on, it draws current both from the solar cell and the cap.

So while the buck input current is chopped, and the solar cell current is continuous, if voltage on the cap stays constant (ignoring ripple), both currents have the same average value.

Answer (score 1):

The reality is that there always **some** inductance between the solar cell and the capacitor at the input of the buck converter.  This would be in the wires you use to connect the panel to your buck converter.

Let's assume you connect the solar panel to the buck converter using 1-metre length of 2-core cable, the cable contains two individual insulated copper wires, each sized AWG#18 (about 1mm diameter).  This cable will have a total inductance of about 19 micro-henries (note 1 below).  It will also have a total resistance of about 42 milli-ohms.  The circuit formed by the inductance of 19uH and the input capacitance of 1000uH has a resonant frequency of about 1.15kHz, so provided that the switching frequency of the boost converter is well above this, the capacitor will supply most of the pulsating current, while the solar panel cell will supply almost constant current (the same current flowing in the 19uH inductor).

Note 1: Standard 2-core cable, sometimes called "twin", is a type of multi-core cable that has two individual wires running in parallel, with an overall sheath that holds the wires against each other.   In your case, one wire connects to the positive, the other connects to the negative.  Geometrically, this cable and the two devices connected at each end, form a current path that looks like a rectangle having a length of 1meter, the wires are separated by a small distance, much smaller than its length - in this case, we can ignoring the insulation thickness, where the two wires are placed close to one.  You can look up the formula for the inductance of a narrow rectangle, under the section headed "THE SELF-INDUCTANCE OF A RETURN CIRCUIT" on page 151 of the famous publication: "Formulas & Tables for Calcn of Mutual & Self-Inductance", authored by ROSA & GROVER, published 1947, link:

https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/bulletin/08/nbsbulletinv8n1p1_A2b.pdf